# Jodconverter: Could not open document: tempfile.docx

Tags: libreoffice, jodconverter

This is a problem we were facing when converting docx to pdf's using jodconverter in 4 parallel streams (and 4 instances of Libreoffice, running on a docker container) and the processing failed after some iterations. Error was:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Could not open document: tempfile_39.docx
at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:225)
at org.jodconverter.local.task.AbstractLocalOfficeTask.loadDocument(AbstractLocalOfficeTask.java:118)
at org.jodconverter.local.task.LocalConversionTask.execute(LocalConversionTask.java:117)
at org.jodconverter.local.office.OfficeProcessManagerPoolEntry.doExecute(OfficeProcessManagerPoolEntry.java:187)
at org.jodconverter.core.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.lambda$execute$0(AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.java:83)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could not find anything related to this, so created a question.

Answer (score 1):

We tried reducing max conversions per process (https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/issues/124) but it did not work. As far as i understand, it is due to how jodconverter's abstract office manager names file. It uses an atomic counter (tempfile_{count}.docx} ([Source](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/blob/0dbddecddd690035eaa7b89ed5a2b9bda1172a6a/jodconverter-core/src/main/java/org/jodconverter/core/office/AbstractOfficeManager.java#L85)) to name temp files which can lead to conflicts in parallel processing.

Workaround that worked for us was **let it do parallel processing, if it fails fallback to sequential processing**. Sequential processing was far robust for us.